# What to do when a meta post is marked as status-completed, but not fixed in reality?

Tags: support, meta

Scenario:

1. Alice reports an SE issue via meta, being confirmed and voted.
2. After some time Bob posts an answer: *"This will be fixed in the next build"* and marks Alice's post as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).
3. Alice still sees the bug after 3 months and comments to the Bob's answer saying that the issue is not fixed.
4. Bob doesn't answer.

What Alice should do? Post another meta question?

<sup><sub>[Example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225860/205508)</sub></sup>

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's no perfect solution here. Sometimes, bugs do regress; sometimes, they were never fixed to begin with...

...and sometimes, there are multiple bugs and only one gets fixed.

If you're *confident* that it's the *exact same bug*, then just update the original report to note that it is still occurring as of [date] and [build]. **Make sure you've followed the instructions in [the bug tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bug/info)** concerning a clear description of the problem and steps to reproduce - then flag the post and request that the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag be removed per your edit.

Otherwise, post a new report, referencing the old one but again being sure to **follow the instructions in [the bug tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bug/info)** *i-cannot-stress-enough-that-if-it-cannot-be-understood-or-reproduced-it-will-probably-not-be-given-any-attention!*

Comment: The second link in the bug tag wiki seems broken. It links to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=bugs, but that page doesn't exist. I think it should be http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tagged/bugs instead.

Comment: *just update the original report to note that it is still occurring as of [date] and [build]* - How can I know if the current deployed version is supposed to fix the issue that I reported? I mean, how can I know when the latest build was deployed?

Comment: You don't, @IonicãBizãu - but you know the current date and you can find the current build by checking the footer of the site where you observe the bug (should be the very last thing on the page). And thanks - I fixed those links.

Comment: @Shog9 Oh, I see it. I updated my another question with a recent screen shot. I hope the guys will fix it. :-)

Comment: I think your space key is broken.